# Install SSL on VPS Google App Engine for https

Tags: ssl, vps, https, google-app-engine

I have VPS Ubuntu 14 Server My GAE application on pyton.
My Python application is using HTTP on Google App Engine. I have an SSL certificate for my domain, and I'd like my Google App Engine application to use HTTPS. How do I do this for my application's domain on Google App Engine?

Comment: Did you try Googling "GAE SSL"? The very first result is https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to the Google Cloud Platform Console. Open up your project. Go to the SSL certificates page and then click the "Upload New Certificate" button.

And how do I know this to be true? Because I'm an unparalleled genius! <sup>1</sup>

<sub><sub><sub>[1 Not really I just know how to use Google and you can be too with a little effort.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_ssl_to_your_custom_domain)</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Hey, nice hat. :)